# How do I get remote access to Windows 10 on macOS?

Tags: windows-10, macos, remote-desktop

Can anyone provide some guidance as to how I can remotely access my windows 10 laptop from my MacBook Pro?

Comment: You can use Microsoft's Remote Desktop Assistant to achieve this. There are many portals with the tutorials on how to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Store - search 'Microsoft Remote Desktop' - freeware.

There are two versions by MS themselves.
Get the new one with the circular icon, not the old one with the square.

[image]

Picture from new Mojave App Store, but the process is the same for the older Store app.